# How to make Json.NET set IsSpecified properties for properties with complex values?

Tags: asp.net, json, xml, json.net, xsd2code

I have a web service built with ASP.Net, which until now only used XML for its input and output. Now it needs to also be able to work with JSON.

We use xsd2code++ to generate the model from a XSD, with the option to create ["IsSpecified" properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/zds0b35c(v=vs.100)) enabled (i.e. if a property is specified in a XML, its respective "Specified" property will be `true`).

From a XSD like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="Person">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Details" type="PersonalDetails"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  
  
  <xs:complexType name="PersonalDetails">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

... xsd2code++ creates a class, with properties like this:

```
public partial class Person
{
    #region Private fields
    private string _id;
    private PersonalDetails _details;
    private Address _address;
    private bool _iDSpecified;
    private bool _detailsSpecified;
    private bool _addressSpecified;
    #endregion

    public Person()
    {
        this._address = new Address();
        this._details = new PersonalDetails();
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id;
        }
        set
        {
            this._id = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public PersonalDetails Details
    {
        get
        {
            return this._details;
        }
        set
        {
            this._details = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public Address Address
    {
        get
        {
            return this._address;
        }
        set
        {
            this._address = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore()]
    public bool IDSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this._iDSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this._iDSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore()]
    public bool DetailsSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this._detailsSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this._detailsSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore()]
    public bool AddressSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this._addressSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this._addressSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This works great for XML.
For example, if ID isn't specified in the input XML, the property IDSpecified will be `false`. We can use these "Specified" properties in the business logic layer, so we know what data has to be inserted/updated, and what can be ignored/skipped.

Then, we tried to add JSON serialization.
We added a Json formatter to the WebApiConfig class:

```
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
```

The API will now recognize JSON inputs, but the "Specified" properties don't work for complex objects as they do for XML, and will always say they're `false`.

```
{
    "ID": "abc123", // IDSpecified comes through as "true"
    "Details": { // DetailsSpecified always comes through as "false"
        "FirstName": "John", // FirstNameSpecified = true
        "LastName": "Doe", // LastNameSpecified = true
        "BirthDate": "1990-06-20" // BirthDateSpecified = true
    }
}
```

Is Newtonsoft's DefaultContractResolver not fully compatible with these "Specified" fields, like XML is? Am I expected to explicitly state for each property if its "Specified" value is true?
Or am I missing something?

**EDIT**:
I've uploaded some sample code to GitHub: https://github.com/AndreNobrega/XML-JSON-Serialization-POC

The request bodies I've tried sending can be found in the Examples folder of the project. POST requests can be sent to .../api/Person.
When sending the XML example, I set the `Content-Type` header to `application/xml`. When sending the JSON example, I set it to `application/json`.

If you set a breakpoint in the Post() method of the PersonController class, you will see that `xxxSpecified` members for XML requests are set correctly, but not for JSON.

Maybe it's got something to do with the Person.Designer class, that is auto-generated by xsd2code++? Is there a JSON equivalent for the attribute `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]`?

Comment: Json.Net supports the `Specified` property convention out of the box, as shown [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Iyry36).  What is the actual JSON you are deserializing?  Does it match the shape of your classes?

Comment: @BrianRogers The JSON I'm deserializing is the last block of code in the OP, and it does match my classes. The difference between my code and yours, is that instead of calling JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(), the deserialization is done by a JsonMediaTypeFormatter (the one in the penultimate code block), before arriving at the controller.

Comment: Still can't reproduce if I use [`JsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/mt134688(v=vs.118)) to deserialize, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/zWBnxW.  Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?

Comment: The `xxxIsSpecified` pattern is definitely supported by Json.NET, see e.g. [How to force Newtonsoft Json to serialize all properties? (Strange behavior with “Specified” property)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39223335/3744182) and [XSD.EXE + JSON.NET - How to deal with xxxSpecified generated members?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32403419/3744182) for example questions.

Comment: You might check to see whether you are setting [`DefaultContractResolver.IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers.htm) somewhere.

Comment: Is there any chance you preallocate `Details` in the `Person` constructor?  If you do, Json.NET will populate the pre-existing instance and not set back a new instance, and so it seems `DetailsSpecified` never gets set.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/0taaIn.  For comparison `XmlSerializer` never populates existing instances of non-collection types.

Comment: @dbc Thanks for the replies. I've added an example to the OP, to better illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @dbc I have tried setting `DefaultContractResolver.IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers`, but as it's to be expected, the formatter then returns all `xxxSpecified` as false.
When xsd2code++ generates the classes, it does initialize `Address` and `PersonalDetails` (see /Models/Person.Designer.cs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have encountered a limitation in Json.NET's support for [`{propertyName}Specified` members](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreIsSpecifiedMembers.htm): **the `{propertyName}Specified` property is not set when populating an instance of a *preallocated* reference type property.**  As a workaround, you can deserialize with the setting [`JsonSerializerSettings.ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_ObjectCreationHandling.htm).  If you do, new instances of reference type properties will be created by the serializer and set back after creation, thereby toggling the corresponding `{propertyName}Specified` property.

A detailed explanation follows.  In your `Person` type, you automatically allocate instances of the child properties `Address` and `Details` in the default constructor:

```
public Person()
{
    this._address = new Address();
    this._details = new PersonalDetails();
}
```

Now, because Json.NET supports [populating an existing object](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PopulateObject.htm), during deserialization, after calling your default `Person()` constructor, it will populate the values of `Address` and `Details` that you constructed, rather than creating new ones.  And because of that, it apparently never calls the setters for `Address` and `Details`, perhaps because Newtonsoft assumed there was no need to do so.  But that, in turn, seems to prevent the corresponding `Specified` properties from being set, as it appears Json.NET toggles them only when the setter is called.

(For comparison, `XmlSerializer` never populates preallocated reference type properties other than collection-valued properties, so this situation situation should not arise with `XmlSerializer`.)

This might be a bug in Json.NET's implementation of the `{propertyName}Specified` pattern.  You might want to [open an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) about it with Newtonsoft.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0taaIn).

As a workaround, you could:

- Deserialize with the setting [`JsonSerializerSettings.ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_ObjectCreationHandling.htm) like so:

  ```
  config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace;
  ```

  This option will *Always create new objects* and thereby triggers the setting of `Specified` properties.

  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z5L3Yq).
- Remove allocation of `Address` and `Details` from the default constructor for `Person`.  Not really recommended, but it does solve the problem.

  Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/scBVHZ).

Comment: Adding `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace;` to the formatter settings seems to make it behave just like the XML formatter, without needing any changes to the model. This should work, thank you!